# Is it possible to load web worker inside a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, web-worker

Hi I'm really new to Angular and trying to understand web workers.

So far I have two async workers but here is now my problem.
The first one is taking too long until it renders the output.
The second one has already finished and rendered everything in the frontend.
The user can interact with the site even if the first worker isn't ready yet. But this will cause sometimes problems.

So my solution is to encapsulate the tow workers with a promise and call e.g. $q.all() to render the output of both workers when they have finished gathering all needed informations.

But my current understanding for the initialization of web workers is that I can trigger them e.g. in a
- webpack.config.js
or
- tsconfig.worker.json
So I don't know how or if I can't call all workers by my own script.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, but not in the traditional way. After 1 minute of Googling I found an article on Codeburst, explaining the what's and how's of async workers:

https://codeburst.io/promises-for-the-web-worker-9311b7831733

In a nutshell: by wrapping a `worker` in a `Class` and instantiating that `Class`, binding the `onmessage` attribute on `construct`, you can fully intercept/handle all functionality.

Comment: TY, I will give it a try.